# Adding external javascript in views codeigniter4 not the assets uses base_url()

Tags: codeigniter-4

I'm using codeigniter 4. I have been doing ajax request directly to a view file.  Now I want to
use external ajax_file_name.js and call it inside that view

```
My Views directory looks like this:

--| Views
-----| Products
---------| index.php
---------| ajaxFolder
--------------|ajax_operation.js
```

I always do ajax in index like this

```
Views/ Products/ index.php

$(function($){
    
    //my ajax cruds functions goes here

})(jQuery);
```

But now I want to be able to use ajax external file like this:

```
Views/ Products/ index.php

<script src="/ajaxFolder/ajax_operation.js"></script>

Controllers/Product.php

public function index()
{
    return view("Products/index");
}
```

How can I achieve that since controller load php file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you will need to move your js files to CodeIgniters public folder. This way, when you access the file from the web server, the path you have shown will be inside the correct folder. As you may know, the public folder is the default "web root folder" for CI4.

```
--| app
-----| Views
--------| Products
------------| index.php
--| public
-----| ajaxFolder
----------| ajax_operation.js
```

With this structure, the script tag you have shown in your view will path correctly in the browser.

`<script src="/ajaxFolder/ajax_operation.js"></script>`

For reference, this is the [CI4 docs](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/concepts/structure.html) on the folder structure.

Comment: Your solution works, but for better organization I think it will be best if ajax file kept on the same directory level of the view, that is what I wanted to solve. What alternative to that without using $this->include?

Comment: These are your main two options. If you want to keep it outside of public, you must include it. If you want to use the script tag as shown, you must put it in public. This is because, for security reasons, your web server cannot go "up" out of the public folder. A third option, outside the scope of this discussion, is to use an asset manager such as npm or yarn and compile your assets into the public folder at deploy time or runtime.

Comment: Thank you colonelclick! I have one more question. how i can set .env values using controller please?

Comment: That answer can really vary depending on what you are trying to do. I am happy to answer but it would be better to make a new question for this instead of trying to talk about in comments. But feel free to message me if you make a new question.

Comment: Thank you. I arledy find a solution to this. I replaced the values with preg_replace of database config with form inputs.